# Python Error: TypeError: Append() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, append

I am writing a python script and have set my variables. But I keep getting this error

```
"TypeError: Append() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)"
```

I had a look online and it says restart my python window but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Below is a simple version of what i have.  The append code works in ArcGIS Pro so I am assuming my setup is incorrect in IDLE.

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.today().strftime('%b%y') #'Dec20'

# Local variables:
i.e
Leases_x = L:\\{}\\SA\\production\\product\\leases.gdb\\Leases".format(d)
Leases_Y = L:\\{}\\SA\\production\\product\\leases.gdb\\LeasesY".format(d)
Leases_Z = L:\\{}\\SA\\production\\product\\leases.gdb\\LeasesZ".format(d)
... ect

# Process: Append
arcpy.management.Append("'Leases_x ';'Leases_Y '; 'Leases_Z'; 'Leases_S'; 'Leases_T'", 'Leases_A', 'NO_TEST', "", "", "")
```

Comment: `'data1'` is not the same as `data1` you know that right, see @Aarons answer? If you use `data1` then maybe arcpy thinks your path is `r"L:\Support\Data_load\Tenements\Dec20\SA\L:\Support\Data_load\Tenements\Dec20\SA\Mineral l - production\Private_mines_gdb\Private_mines.gdb\Private_Mines'` which cant be right? Im not sure how clever arcpy is

Comment: I cant believe im so stuck on a little append :|... I thought if i put data1 = r'L:\Support\Data_load..' that means when i do my append process it will refer back to it?  Yes that is what the path is for data1. But yeah i thought data1 and 'data1' are the same? Just data1 is the path and 'data1' is refering back to it?

Comment: Oh my, i just took off the ' ' and i think it has worked. Such an egg i missed that. Thanks for your help guys i was stuck on it for hours!

Comment: Nice! (When you are using `'data1'` then there must be a feature class in the workspace named `data1`)

Comment: Oh i understand, that makes sense. Thank you. I didn't know that. :) :)

Comment: I've rolled your question back to the version that @Aaron answered.  If you have a new question then please ask it as one rather than stranding any existing answers.  You can always link to this one, if it has any important background relevant to your new question.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to a variety of syntax errors, you are getting the `TypeError` because you are passing 6 parameters to the tool rather than the maximum of 5. These are:

```
1. "'Leases_x ';'Leases_Y '; 'Leases_Z'; 'Leases_S'; 'Leases_T'"
2. 'Leases_A'
3. 'NO_TEST'
4. ""
5. ""
6. ""
```

---

The [Append (Data Management) documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) states the following are the valid parameters:

```
Append(inputs, target, {schema_type}, {field_mapping}, {subtype})
```

where `inputs` is a list of input datasets to append to the target dataset.

Here is a simplified example of how you would run Append:

```
import arcpy

target = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\target'

data1 = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\data1'
data2 = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\data2'
data3 = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\data3'

arcpy.Append_management([data1, data2, data3], target)
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much, i understand why i was getting the 6 errors now. I am now getting a different error: ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Target Dataset: Dataset Mineral_Leases does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Append).

Comment: Please follow the code example I provided. There are several syntax errors with your paths.

Comment: Hi Aaron, i copied your code and pasted in my paths but i still get the same error.

Comment: Aaron added my paths to my question above.

Comment: Are you referring to the `ExecuteError`? Can you please let me know how you passed the path string to a variable e.g. `data1 = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\data1'`?